# Visual Studio 2015 hangs

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a system which I have updated from W7 to W10. The W7 was a very basic system with just Adobe, Avast, Chrome, Office 2010 and the standard programs that came with the DELL E6400.

I made a very simple program and put a BP on the first line. Then I pressed "Local Windows Debugger". The program compiled OK but then VS hung. It hung with the swirl continually running. It hung so bad that I could not cause an exit by clicking the close button.

Task manager shows it is running with 1.8% CPU and no disk or network activity.

Suspecting a problem with the W10 upgrade I tried the same thing on my E6440 but got the same result.

I searched the internet looking for a problem like this but have not found anything. I ran Windows Update and it did not mention an update for VS2015.

Has anyone seen this problem? Does anyone have any ideas as to how to run it down?

Comment: Disable avast. And try again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613454/why-dont-my-programs-work-using-codeblocks#comment55002071_33613454

Comment: Hay, that worked. I only tried it once. It is getting late here ... I'll try it again tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Avast is the most likely cause. If I disable a feature called "Deep Screen" then I don't have the problem. Since I never had the problem before I suspect that there was an Avast update that is now causing the problem.

It could be that DeepScreen is the feature that causes Avast to scan a program that it has never seen just as drescherjm has described.

So for all using VS2015, uncheck Settings->DeepScreen in Avast.

Answer (score 0):

Some antivirus software like avast are known to cause this type of behavior on unknown applications. All programs that you write will be unknown at least the first build so the application will be run in a sandbox to verify that they do not exhibit virus like behavior. Your antivirus should allow exceptions to turn off this sandboxing for specific paths which may be your best option as a programmer.

Comment: I am aware of this Avast feature. I never get the Avast screen showing that it is checking for a virus.