# Visual Studio hangs when I hit debug

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I've tried both VS2013 and the latest, 2015 with the same, incredibly simple chunk of code, and both programs completely freeze when I press debug/hit f5!

The mouse changes to a loading wheel except nothing happens and eventually I force close the program!
Any suggestion is helpful, 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to deactivate/remove your antivirus software.

Comment: Wow thank you, here I am looking for really technical solutions to this and didn't even think of that! Thank you very much

Comment: It's a common issue. It has been asked several times lately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is commonly caused by some anti-virus.

- [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2010/12/16/how-to-solve-visual-studio-hang-problem-when-working-in-win7-with-norton-antivirus.aspx) is a solution for Norton Antivirus.
- And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33694953/890890) for Avast.